# Proper way to connect two NodeJS servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am trying to build an app to retrieve data from a local database, The structure of the app that I have a mobile app, server(on a hosting service), and local server(on my pc), I am trying to make the mobile app request data from the server via a normal HTTP request then the server request the data from the local server but the problem that I could not be able to connect with my local server I believe that I could not connect to my local server because my local server does not have a public IP, so I am trying to find a better way to achieve my idea.

[image: An Image describing the app structure]

I read something about Websocket but I don't know if it suitable for my idea beacuse it is Bi-directional  connection and It most used for chatting app

I want to build the app with NodeJs, so what should I do to implement this idea, and thank you for the help.

Comment: Both your server and local server are on the same network?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "local"? Local to the same network as the "server"?

Comment: Please post the code you tried to connect to your database server, without that we can hardly help. But yes, it is a fairly standard setup to have the database running on a separate server.

Comment: This is very common. @obeda are both of them on the same network? Are you setting IP addresses correctly. What you are trying to do is fairly common. Are 2 Docker containers involved in any way shape or form which would require you to keep both the servers on the same network

Comment: Each server is on a different network the main server is on Heroku host and the local server is on my personal computer

Comment: Maybe you could keep an open SSH tunnel from your 'local' to 'server'. See https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example

Comment: I think it's worth asking why the remote server needs to request data from your local server. Why not just put everything in a location where the pieces can easily talk to each other?

Comment: @JLRishe the data is connected to a different program that changes the data soIt will be a lot difficult to change the data location the idea is to make the program data accessible on the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each server is on a different network the main server is on Heroku host and the local server is on my personal computer

Life would be a lot easier for you if you move your local server to Heroku where they can much more easily and securely talk to one another.

You can't connect from your Heroku server to the server on your private local network because it is behind a firewall in your home router.  To allow such a connection, you have to configure a known public IP address for your home network (that won't change or use DDNS if it can change) and configure port forwarding in your firewall/router so incoming connections from the internet on a specific port can reach your local server.  You will then have to harden your local server against random internet attacks since it will then be open to the internet.

One other possibility is that you could have your local server connect to your Heroku server (perhaps with a webSocket connection using some sort of secret credential).   Since your Heroku server is already reachable from your home network, this would require less networking configuration change.  Depending upon what you're trying to do between the two servers, you could either have the local server just make a regular http request to the Heroku server (either sending data or asking for data) or you could make a webSocket connection and then data can be sent either way of the webSocket connection.